# ColdFusion SELECT with INNER JOIN from Form

Tags: forms, coldfusion

I'm having some trouble with getting info from a ColdFusion form to an action page and displaying what is needed. I have to display the selected product and the CompanyName for this product, based on product selected from the form.

Here is the code from my form page:

```
<form action="productinfo.cfm" method="post">
   <cfoutput query = "getProducts">
     ...
     <input type="radio" name="prods" value="#getProducts.productname#">
     #getProducts.productname#
     ...
   </cfoutput>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Here is the code from my action page:

```
 <cfset prodname = form.prods>

 <cfquery name = "JoinProdSupp" datasource = "jeb48_northwind">
     SELECT  Products.ProductName, Suppliers.CompanyName
     FROM    Suppliers INNER JOIN Products 
                ON Suppliers.SupplierID = Products.SupplierID
     WHERE  (((Products.ProductName)='#prodname#'));
   </cfquery>
```

I'm not exactly sure how to output the contents of the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure I figured this out... if anyone has any comments I'm all ears. this is what I ended up with.

```
     <cfoutput query = "JoinProdSupp">
       #JoinProdSupp.ProductName#<br>
       #JoinProdSupp.CompanyName#<br>
     </cfoutput>
```

Comment: When you ran your query, you should have used a query parameter for a variety of reasons.  In your output code, since you have a query attribute in your cfoutput tag, qualifying the variable with the query name is unnecessary.

Comment: @DanBracuk is right, and to be clear, he means <cfqueryparam> like this..     WHERE (((Products.ProductName)=<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#prodName#">)). CFQueryParam is a crucial defense against sql injections. http://help.adobe.com/livedocs/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=Tags_p-q_18.html. Also notice the lack of quotes around the <cfqueryparam> tag, cfqueryparam adds quotes as dictated by the cfsqltype selected.

Comment: The query name is indeed unnecessary, but if that cfoutput block grows and gets more complicated, it's really nice to have it there, especially when someone else comes along and is trying to figure out where the variables are coming from.

Answer (score 1):

For reference..

Any time you want to understand the contents of any CF variable, (array, struct, query, any of those nested in any of those, nested in any of those) you can use CFDUMP.

```
<cfdump var="#MyQuery#">
```

(Note the hashes around the variable name, those are important.)

Watch what happens if you execute this script. (This script uses syntax from CF 8 or above)

```
<cfscript>
  s_struct = {}; // Create an empty structure.
  s_struct.sample_array = ["sample","array","data"]; // Create an array with three elements
  s_struct.sample_array[4] = {one = 1,banana = "yellow"}; // Add a fourth element to the same array, whose content is a struct with two elements.
  s_struct.second_array = [{cat = "dog", red = "blue", big = "small"},{cat = "feline", dog = "canine", big = "large"}];
  s_struct.FirstArraySize = ArrayLen(s_struct.sample_array);
</cfscript>

<cfdump var="#s_struct#">
```

The output of a cfdump basically teaches you how you can access the contents of a variable, which can be helpful with poorly documented web-services, or tables that you can't access directly. Just remember to always clean up the cfdumps from production.